# Apose.Total cannot find license file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, aspose

I am currently using Aspose Total in one of my Libraries,  When I import this library into an application it works well as my License is embedded.

However when I switch this library from debug to release it then gives an error when running the application saying 'Cannot find Aspose.Total.lic'

Is there anyone with experience with Aspose that might know the problem.

I include my Projbuild Set.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{B6C9F754-6764-4D2A-B1A4-C0047152BE33}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>NitecCore</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>NitecCore</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>
    </TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;CSHARP30</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;CSHARP30;  </DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you set lic.Embedded to true as in below code snippet:

```
Aspose.Pdf.License lic = new Aspose.Pdf.License(); 
lic.SetLicense("MergedAPI.Aspose.Total.Product.Family.lic");
lic.Embedded = true;
```

For reference, please check http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/396532/aspose-pdf-cannot-find-the-embedded-license-file.aspx

Comment: Yep I have done this however it works on Debug mode but not Release

Comment: Share your environment details and the version of the API you are using at your end.

Answer (score 2):

Another cause can be due to the license being not available in output folder 
Right click Aspose.lic file and select property

[image]

Select Build action to ***Content*** and  Copy to output  directory  --> ***copy  always / copy if newer***

Answer (score 0):

I am working as Social Media developer at Aspose. Check the details of embedding license [here](http://goo.gl/YImnxa). In case you still face any issue, share the version of Aspose API you are using and environment details, so we can test further.

Comment: I know it's old, may be you don't work there any more but:Why do Aspose forums require you to log in before you can even view a post?! Most annoying UX; you should only have to log in if you want to post.